# Browser is not reloading images that are in css (background swap on mouseover or other events)

Tags: browser, browser-cache

Sometimes browsers are not reloading images.  Especially images that are in css.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Never saw any question like this in SO. The answer is self contained.

Comment: While this information might be useful; Stack Overflow is a question and answer website, not a blogging platform (even for useful tips). Please phrase this as a question. And then supply your solutions as an answer to that question. Otherwise you run the risk of this being closed as 'not a real question' (as it isn't *any* kind of question). Please see: [What's the best way to post a tutorial on SO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89333/whats-the-best-way-to-post-a-tutorial-on-so)

Comment: That's a good tip, and I think your intentions are good here, but this isn't what Stack Overflow is for.  It's a question and answer website.  This sort of post would belong in a personal blog.  If you really feel the need to share this sort of information here, then you should post a question first (that isn't a duplicate), then answer it, then accept your answer.

Comment: sounds to me like you should be writing a blog post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a nice idea, but in its current form it doesn't fully fit the Q&A format. It *might* work if you split it up into a question and an answer you give yourself - maybe worth a try?

Comment: Like David and @Shiplu said, it's uncommon, but [allowed](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: I divided my post to question - answer. Is that better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, when we creating website - we change images many times. Sometimes images are cached and they are not refreshing.

The best example are **images, that browser loads on "mouseover" or "click" events** (menu backgrounds for example) are really frustrating, because there is no way to refresh them with F5 or Ctrl+F5, because they are not displayed. They can ruin your day :D

**HOW TO DISABLE CACHE IN POPULAR BROWSERS TUTORIAL**

IMPORTANT: don't forget what you turned off/on - you may need cache later when you will work on 56k modem :D or 3G connection.

**How to disable cache in Google Chrome:**

1. Open Chrome Developer Tools (by menu, or shortcut Ctrl+Shift+I).
2. Click gear icon in right bottom corner (settings)
3. In settings of Developer Tools there is an option "Disable cache".

**How to disable cache in Mozilla Firefox:**

1. Type or paste "about:config" in address bar.
2. Accept message from scary window (new versions) :)
3. Find "network.http.use-cache" and double-click it.
4. To reenable - double-click again.

**How to disable cache in Opera?**

1. Type "opera:config" in address bar.
2. Find Cache section.
3. There are many helpful options. You can:

   - set image expiry in cache
   - permanent disable cache for images (its called "Cache Figs")
   - permanent disable cache for documents

**How to disable cache in Internet Explorer 9**

*(unfortunately i dont have english version, so i can make mistake translating)*

1. Turn on Developer Tools (shorcut key F12)
2. Expand developer tools window if you dont see menu
3. Find Cache in that menu and there should be an option "Always Refresh from Server"

Alternative for IE (older versions without developer tools):
You can find "Always Refresh from Server" option in IE settings.